# A registration already exists for URI in windows service hosted WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor

I have a WCF service library hosted by a windows service. I am using Castle Windson to do constructor injection. When I try to start up the service I get an exception with the following inner exception:

```
{"A registration already exists for URI 'net.tcp://localhost:8056/LoggingServiceWCF/tcp'."}
```

**App.config:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="LoggingServiceWCF.LoggingService">
        <endpoint address="tcp" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="netTcp" contract="LoggingServiceWCF.ILoggingService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="tcpMex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="mexTcp" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="pipe" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="namedPipe" contract="LoggingServiceWCF.ILoggingService" />
        <endpoint address="pipeMex" binding="mexNamedPipeBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" bindingConfiguration="" name="mexPipe" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8056/LoggingServiceWCF" />
            <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/LoggingServiceWCF"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Castle windsor installer:**

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
   container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();
   container.Register(Component
                      .For<LoggerServiceCore.Interfaces.ILogger>()
                      .ImplementedBy<LogManager>(),
                      Component
                      .For<ILoggingService>()
                      .ImplementedBy<LoggingService>()
                      .LifeStyle.Transient
                      .AsWcfService());

            container.Register(Component
                                .For<ServiceBase>()
                                .ImplementedBy<LoggingHostService>());
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
static class Program
{
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
#if DEBUG
            Debugger.Launch();
#endif
            ServiceBase.Run(CreateContainer().Resolve<ServiceBase>());
        }

        private static IWindsorContainer CreateContainer()
        {
            var container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
            return container;
        }
}
```

**Windows service class:**

```
    public partial class LoggingHostService : ServiceBase
    {
            internal static ServiceHost service = null;

            public LoggingHostService()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {
                if(service != null)
                {
                    service.Close();
                }

                service = new ServiceHost(typeof(LoggingServiceWCF.LoggingService));
                service.Open();
            }

            protected override void OnStop()
            {
                if(service != null)
                {
                    service.Close();
                    service = null;
                }
            }
   }
```

I have Googled around and found all kinds of solutions to similar issues, but I can't seem to find something that works in my case.